# Python does not read the Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an excel sheet and create a pandas data frame out of it, but it keeps saying that the sheet does not exist, even tho it actually exists. Has anyone faced something similar?

This is the code I used:

```
    excel=pd.ExcelFile("Berlin_Club_List.xlsx")
    clubs=pd.read_excel(excel, 'Berlin_Club_List')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in your working directory?
If it is not you need to provide full path

(Would be a comment but not enough rep)

Comment: yes, it is in the working directory. It reads the excel file, but it does not read the sheet only

Answer (score 0):

To check your actual working directory you can do the following:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Do show the actual error message that you got. This will help others to understand and debug the issue you are facing.

Definitely check the documentation for pd.read_excel by typing

```
pd.read_excel?
```

you will see that you can specify the sheet you want to by

```
pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name='sheetname')
```

and so on.